# capabilities URL for open street map

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap

I want to use open street map as cascading WMS to my Geoserver. Which capabilities URL should i use?

Can any body tell me the capabilities URL for OSM ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling "openstreetmap wms" points me to the following link 
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS#OSM_WMS_Servers which looks plausible but I haven't tried any of them out to see if they work.

Comment: This are 'hit or miss' unless your in Germany where there seems plentiful of OSM WMS Servers..

Comment: original poster didn't say where they lived :-)

Comment: users IP suggests Sweden.

Answer (score 1):

The best list I have found is

http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/frmts/wms/WMSServerList.txt

[image]